# Cannot Install Visual Studio 2015 Community on Windows 7

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Every time I try to install visual studio community version I run into an issue with missing setup packages. The installer particularly tells me that I am missing vcredist_x86.exe.
[image: vcredist_x86.exe]

However, I have installed the visual c++ redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2013 as well as the ones for visual studio 2015. I don't get why this message keeps coming up.

I can continue installation if I select "skip", but the message comes back not much later.

Comment: Usually it downloads the missing ones itself. Did you try to remove your installed ones and re-install, or let the setup handle it ?

Answer (score 0):

Try running the installer with administrator rights (right click on installer exe and select 'Run as administrator').